# Hotkeys for web application buttons

Tags: asp.net

I have a command button on my web app, when I click on the button I want it to act like it is entering keystrokes (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>). Is there any way to do this, and if so, how?

Comment: What's the goal here?  Open the file browser dialog from javascript?